# Прежний вы "мёртв и навсегда забыт" или "мертвы и забыты"?

Tags: число

Уважаемые эксперты!
Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант и почему верен:

"Сегодня вы другой человек. Прежний вы уже мёртв и навсегда забыт"
или
"Сегодня вы другой человек. Прежний вы уже мертвы и навсегда забыты"?

Comment: Лариса, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, я этого не знала, теперь буду так делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Прежний вы"* — это *"он"*, воспринимается как некое третье лицо. Это уже не тот *"вы"*, к которому обращаются. И поэтому, на мой слух, здесь уместно согласование по третьему лицу и единственному числу: **Сегодня вы другой человек. Прежний вы уже мёртв и навсегда забыт.**

Comment: Определение перед местоимением не надо обособить?

Comment: @shampar по общему правилу вроде бы надо, но здесь опят вступает в дело то, что "прежний вы" ощущается как третье лицо, отдельное от нынешнего "вы". Я как-то обсуждал с филологами это, и они сказали, что обособление в таких случаях не требуется. Также я обсуждал это с сотрудниками проекта "Современный русский" и получил такой же ответ: https://i.imgur.com/MrRLa92.png

Answer (score 2):

Лучше написать так: ***Сегодня вы другой человек. Вы прежний уже мёртв и навсегда забыт.***

Перестановка нужна для ясности структуры предложения и лучшей сочетаемости слов по числу (прежний уже мёртв).

Второе предложение с двунаправленной связью: прилагательное "прежний" согласуется в числе со сказуемым (прежний мертв), а в мужском роде согласуется с подлежащим "вы".

В первом предложении именной частью сказуемого является сочетание "другой человек".

Comment: Определение, идущее после местоимения, не надо обособить?

Comment: Только как вариант. При двунаправленной связи  предикативная основа и "дуплексив" (определение в данном случае) составляют единое целое.

Comment: @Sharon у Розенталя, кстати, оговорок нет (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#_=_ пункт 10), что создаёт у впервые столкнувшихся с такой ситуацией диссонанс.

Comment: @Sharon и я, между прочим, не нашёл правила, где прописывалось бы, как согласовывать в числе словА после "вы". В аг-80 есть небольшая оговорка, но она не исчерпывает вопроса. Есть ещё вот такая статья, но она просто констатирующая статистика: https://www.hse.ru/data/2013/12/05/1336548499/VY_Handout_Barylnikova.pdf А правила так и нет. "Вы сегодня так красивЫ", но "вы сегодня однА" — почему?

Comment: 1. У Розенталя как раз об этом и говорится, то есть о двойной связи: (1) если определение по смыслу связано не только с подлежащим-местоимением, но и со сказуемым. 2. В вашем примере двойной связи нет, обычное согласование: вы красивы.   А "вы одна" это уже из области стилистики, "вы одни" звучит неестественно, манерно, несовременно. Это выбор автора.

Comment: Вы прежние уже мёртвы и навсегда забыты? Так не напишешь, смысл неясен. А единственное число задается в первом предложении –  "другой человек"

Comment: Спасибо всем участникам за помощь!